# How To Set Navigation Bar Item to Back Button

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a standard left back button navigation item in table view.

I animate in a view and in that view it sets the left item to nil for a clean look.  When I dismiss the animated view, i want the left item to go back to the back button that it was originally.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just before setting the button to Nil, why don't you grab a reference to that button and then assign it back once it has loaded?

Comment: that sounds perfect, how exactly can I do this?

Comment: sure, post the code you're using right now and I'll take a look.

Comment: nevermind, i got it working, just added this line:     `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;` and     `self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;`